# Name of algebraic structure (group-like)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups

What is the name of an algebraic structure (group, quasi group, monoid) defined like the following:

- It is a set of three elements: $a,b,c$;
- Has an operation such that when applied to two elements of the group it returns the other element of the group (example: $ab=c$; $cb=a$);
- Has an "identity" structure such as $aa=a$, $bb=b$, $cc=c$;
- It is commutative: $ab=ba$; also $a(ba)=ac=b$.

This is no homework. I'm just trying to define a structure like this in order to learn, but as I'm reading about group-theory and semigroups it doesn't seem to really define this (for example, the "identity" here is ambiguous - so how should I call it?)

Thank you!

Comment: You can call it a commutative magma with identity, although this name is practically meaningless... (you are basically listing all properties within the name)

Comment: Just a remark: what you call identity is usually called idempotence.

Comment: @JonasLinssen so it wouldn't be an identity here? This group doesn't have an identity then?

Comment: Well, the word identity usually refers to either a) the *identity function* $x\mapsto x$ (you take two inputs and produce one output, so this is not the case for you) or b) **one** dedicated *identity element* $e$ (I think the word *unit element* is more common, but I think I have seen the word identity being used somewhere as well) which satisfies $e\ast a = a = a \ast e$ for every $a$ at the same time. So yes, your definition does not have identity in common terminology…

Comment: I'd say "identity element" and "unit element" are about equally common terminology.

Comment: This operation can actually be applied to the game Set (when you take the direct product of four copies of it, one per type of attribute of the card).
Three cards form a set iff combining any two of them results in the third.

Comment: Your axioms force your operation to be non-associative: x(yz) does not necessarily equal (xy)z. For example, a(ab) = ac = b, but (aa)b = ab = c. Is this what you intended?

Answer (score 22):

This is a commutative quasigroup. However, personally I don't find this sort of naming to be particularly illuminating. To my mind the simplest way to think about this operation $\star$ is actually as a ternary relation $\{ (x, y, z) : x \star y = z \}$, where it has a very simple interpretation: if we set $a = 0, b = 1, c = 2$ then the ternary relation is precisely the relation $x + y + z \equiv 0 \bmod 3$. In other words, the operation is

$$x \star y = - x - y \bmod 3.$$

Writing it this way makes the quasigroup property clear and also exhibits an otherwise somewhat hidden $S_3$ symmetry: this condition is invariant under any permutation of $x, y, z$. It's also equivalent to the condition that $x, y, z$ are either all the same or all different, which you may recognize from the game [Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game)).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I'll set this as the correct answer as soon as I'm able to. Where can I learn more from this? Is there a good book on group theory applications?

Comment: @ludicrous: well, I don't know what you mean by "this." This isn't a group so a book on group theory wouldn't cover it. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I'm sorry. I mean algebraic constructions that could be applied to probability, physics, etc.

Comment: @ludicrous: well, that's an extremely broad question and there are many many books that could be written about it. Here's just one book among many, that explains how to use group representation theory to predict the structure of the periodic table: https://www.amazon.com/Linearity-Symmetry-Prediction-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387246371

Answer (score 12):

The structure you are describing is called a *Steiner quasigroup*. The phrase **S**teiner **qua**si**g**roup is sometimes abbreviated 'squag', so some folks call these objects *squags*.

In general, a (finite) *Steiner triple system* is an $(n,3,1)$-block design or a Steiner system of the form $S(2,3,n)$. This terminology means that a Steiner triple system is a finite geometry $\mathfrak S = (P,L)\;(=(\textrm{points},\textrm{lines}))$ which has $|P|=n$ points, $3$ points per line, and any $2$ points of the geometry determine a unique line. The 'algebraization' of such a geometry is called a 'Steiner quasigroup'. This algebraization $\mathfrak Q=(P,*)$ has the set $P$ of points as its underlying set equipped with a multiplication that encodes the lines. If $x\in P$, then one defines $x*x=x$, while if $x, y\in P$, $x\neq y$, then one defines $x*y=z$ iff $z$ is the third point on the unique line through $x$ and $y$. Your structure arises from a Steiner-type geometry $\mathfrak S = (P,L)$ with three points lying on one line ($|P|=3, |L|=1$). The next smallest Steiner quasigroup arises from a Steiner-type geometry with $|P|=7, |L|=7$, called the *Fano plane*.
[image: Fano plane]